# On which site are questions about etymology on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[Especially this one I asked on another site.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98260/how-did-so-many-types-of-larvae-become-known-as-worms?noredirect=1#comment178799_98260)

> How did it come to be that so many types of creatures typically known
> as worms are actually insect larvae? Silkworms are not actually worms
> at all, but larvae of a type of moth. Another example being the Maguey
> worm, which is supposedly the worm in some types of tequila and also
> not a worm, actually also a type of moth-larvae?
>
> I find it curious that Wikipedia would have a creature with the word
> worm in its title, and then the first thing they tell you about it is
> that it is actually an insect. These are just the two examples I came
> across, there are probably more.

I received a comment that said: "it is a language usage question rather than one about a biological concept or mechanism.". If that is true on which English language site this question would fit? Or any other site if it doesn't fit there either.

Just interested in getting it moved here and want certainty that it is on-topic.

Comment: Quick tip - when people *named* things, they didn't necessarily think hard about *what* the thing actually is but sort of what it reminds them of. Small and wiggly? A worm. Similar to how pineapples are neither pines nor apples.

Comment: Considering the topic, you may want to ask on the Biology meta whether they're interested in it as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can generally ask etymology questions on the site for the specific language. In your case, it's English, so [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) would be a fit. Do note that they tend to close questions which can be answered by simply checking [commonly available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/116151) like dictionaries. This may be true for other sites in the network as well; please check their [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) is not a good fit, since learners of a language generally speaking don't bother about etymology. The tag excerpt is rather clear about this.

Linguistics Stack Exchange has an [etymology section](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) too, if you're interested in the historical development of a word across multiple languages.